# Reactjs: How to access variable from one render to another in same component

Tags: reactjs

I have a variable defined inside map in one render function. I want to access same variable in different render  . Something like this:

```
renderFunc1() {
  return(
  <div>
     {
        this.arr.map(list){....} 
     } 
  </div>
 )
}

renderFunc2() {
 <textarea defaultValue={list} />
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more information on your use case? Why do you want to access a variable assigned inside a call to [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) (I would also review the use of map)? There might be a better solution if your problem is better understood.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you would want this, but a structure something like this would make most sense to me:

```
    const ListComponent = () => 
      <div>
         {
            this.arr.map(list){....} 
         } 
      </div>


    renderFunc1() {
     return this.ListComponent
    } 

    renderFunc2() {
     <SomeWrapper List={this.ListComponent} />
    }
```